# How to create an ImageView on finger touch?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have an activity with RelativeLayout and an existing ImageView in it. What I want to do is allow user to create a little picture in a place where he touches the screen. I suppose the process of creating image would be like that:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.something);

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 );
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.ButtonRecalculate);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

relativeLayout.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
```

And the process of getting the coordinates - like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
}

return true;
}
```

But how to combine them? How can I set these coordinates to new ImageView? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
final RelativeLayout rr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rr);
rr.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
            iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
            iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.gr1));
            ((ViewGroup) v).addView(iv);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I didn't test it but it should work.

Comment: I believe it works, but an image is somewhere below my finger. I suppose it's not because of code, but the borders of a picture. Only the background is transparent. Maybe in the place where I touch the screen I generate a picture in it's right top corner and that's why I see it little below. Do you know hot to solve that or I just need another picture?

Comment: I think it is the image try to edit it so that the content is in the center.